# Extremely slow CD-ROM burning

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, hardware, data-cd, burning

When I try to burn a CD-ROM using K3B, the burner slows down from 10x to 0.12x after writing exactly 71MB. Consequently, burning a 142MB live CD takes more than a hour. Why is this happening?

The CD-ROM burner is a OPTIARC DVD RW AD-5690H (firmware revision 4AH5) and the CD-ROM burning tool that K3B uses, is cdrecord 3.0.

**Update: Here is a log from the last burning operation**

```
Devices
-----------------------
OPTIARC DVD RW AD-5690H 4AH5 (/dev/sr0, Cd-r, CD-RW, Cd-rom, Dvd-rom, DVD-R, DVD-RW, DVD-R DL, DVD+R, DVD+RW, DVD+R DL) [Dvd-rom, DVD-R sekventiel, DVD-R dobbeltlag, sekvensielt, DVD-R dobbeltlag og hop-mulighed, DVD-RW begrænset overbrænding, DVD-RW sekventiel, DVD+RW, DVD+R, DVD+R dobbeltlag, Cd-rom, Cd-r, CD-RW] [SAO, TAO, RAW, SAO/R96R, RAW/R16, RAW/R96P, RAW/R96R, Begrænset overbrænding, Lag-hop] [%7]

System
-----------------------
K3b Version: 2.0.2
KDE Version: 4.8.4 (4.8.4)
QT Version:  4.8.2
Kernel:      3.13.6

Used versions
-----------------------
cdrecord: 3.0

cdrecord
-----------------------
scsidev: '/dev/sr0'
devname: '/dev/sr0'
scsibus: -2 target: -2 lun: -2
Warning: Open by 'devname' is unintentional and not supported.
Linux sg driver version: 3.5.27
SCSI buffer size: 64512
/opt/schily/bin/cdrecord: Warning: Cannot read drive buffer.
/opt/schily/bin/cdrecord: Warning: The DMA speed test has been skipped.
Cdrecord-ProDVD-ProBD-Clone 3.00 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu) Copyright (C) 1995-2010 J�rg Schilling
TOC Type: 1 = CD-ROM
Using libscg version 'schily-0.9'.
Driveropts: 'burnfree'
atapi: 1
Device type    : Removable CD-ROM
Version        : 5
Response Format: 2
Capabilities   : 
Vendor_info    : 'OPTIARC '
Identifikation : 'DVD RW AD-5690H '
Revision       : '4AH5'
Device seems to be: Generic mmc2 DVD-R/DVD-RW/DVD-RAM.
Current: CD-R
Profile: DVD+R/DL 
Profile: DVD+R 
Profile: DVD+RW 
Profile: DVD-R/DL layer jump recording 
Profile: DVD-R/DL sequential recording 
Profile: DVD-RW sequential recording 
Profile: DVD-RW restricted overwrite 
Profile: DVD-R sequential recording 
Profile: DVD-ROM 
Profile: CD-RW 
Profile: CD-R (current)
Profile: CD-ROM (current)
Using generic SCSI-3/mmc   CD-R/CD-RW driver (mmc_cdr).
Driver flags   : MMC-3 SWABAUDIO BURNFREE 
Supported modes: TAO PACKET SAO SAO/R96R RAW/R16 RAW/R96P RAW/R96R
Drive buf size : 1273856 = 1244 KB
FIFO size      : 4194304 = 4096 KB
Track 01: data   142 MB        
Total size:      163 MB (16:09.38) = 72704 sectors
Lout start:      163 MB (16:11/29) = 72704 sectors
Current Secsize: 2048
ATIP info from disk:
Indicated writing power: 6
Disk Is not unrestricted
Disk Is not erasable
Disk sub type: Medium Type C, low Beta category (C-) (6)
ATIP start of lead in:  -11231 (97:32/19)
ATIP start of lead out: 359846 (79:59/71)
Disk type:    Short strategy type (Phthalocyanine or similar)
Manuf. index: 27
Manufacturer: Prodisc Technology Inc.
    Capacity  Blklen/Sparesz.  Format-type  Type
        0             2048         0x00  No Media Present or Unknown Capacity
Blocks total: 359846 Blocks current: 359846 Blocks remaining: 287142
Starting to write CD/DVD/BD at speed 24 in real SAO mode for single session.
Last chance to quit, starting real write in 3 seconds.
2 seconds.
1 seconds.
0 seconds. Operation starts.
Waiting for reader process to fill input buffer ... input buffer ready.
BURN-Free is OFF.
Turning BURN-Free on
Performing OPC...
Sending CUE sheet...
/opt/schily/bin/cdrecord: WARNING: Drive returns wrong startsec (0) using -150
Writing pregap for track 1 at -150
Starting new track at sector: 0
Track 01:    0 of  142 MB written.
Track 01:    1 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%)   0.5x.
Track 01:    2 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   1.6x.
Track 01:    3 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]  11.9x.
Track 01:    4 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]  11.6x.
Track 01:    5 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]  12.0x.
Track 01:    6 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]  11.6x.
Track 01:    7 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]  12.0x.
Track 01:    8 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]  11.7x.
Track 01:    9 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]  12.1x.
Track 01:   10 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]  11.7x.
Track 01:   11 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]  12.1x.
Track 01:   12 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]  11.8x.
Track 01:   13 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]  12.2x.
Track 01:   14 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]  11.8x.
Track 01:   15 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]  12.2x.
Track 01:   16 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]  11.9x.
Track 01:   17 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]  12.3x.
Track 01:   18 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]  11.9x.
Track 01:   19 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]  12.3x.
Track 01:   20 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]  12.0x.
Track 01:   21 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]  12.4x.
Track 01:   22 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]  12.0x.
Track 01:   23 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]  12.4x.
Track 01:   24 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]  12.0x.
Track 01:   25 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]  12.5x.
Track 01:   26 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]  12.1x.
Track 01:   27 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]  12.5x.
Track 01:   28 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]  12.1x.
Track 01:   29 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]  12.5x.
Track 01:   30 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]  12.2x.
Track 01:   31 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]  12.6x.
Track 01:   32 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]  12.2x.
Track 01:   33 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]  12.6x.
Track 01:   34 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]  13.0x.
Track 01:   35 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]  12.6x.
Track 01:   36 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]  13.1x.
Track 01:   37 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]  12.7x.
Track 01:   38 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]  13.1x.
Track 01:   39 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]  12.7x.
Track 01:   40 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]  13.2x.
Track 01:   41 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]  12.8x.
Track 01:   42 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]  13.2x.
Track 01:   43 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]  12.8x.
Track 01:   44 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]  13.2x.
Track 01:   45 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]  12.8x.
Track 01:   46 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]  13.3x.
Track 01:   47 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]  12.9x.
Track 01:   48 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]  13.3x.
Track 01:   49 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]  12.9x.
Track 01:   50 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]  13.4x.
Track 01:   51 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]  13.0x.
Track 01:   52 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]  13.4x.
Track 01:   53 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]  13.0x.
Track 01:   54 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]  13.4x.
Track 01:   55 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]  13.0x.
Track 01:   56 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]  13.5x.
Track 01:   57 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]  13.1x.
Track 01:   58 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]  13.5x.
Track 01:   59 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]  13.1x.
Track 01:   60 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]  13.5x.
Track 01:   61 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]  13.2x.
Track 01:   62 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]  13.6x.
Track 01:   63 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]  13.2x.
Track 01:   64 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]  13.6x.
Track 01:   65 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]  14.0x.
Track 01:   66 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]  13.6x.
Track 01:   67 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]  14.1x.
Track 01:   68 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]  13.7x.
Track 01:   69 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]  14.1x.
Track 01:   70 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]  13.7x.
Track 01:   71 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]  14.2x.
Track 01:   72 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   0.2x.
Track 01:   73 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   0.1x.
Track 01:   74 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   0.1x.
Track 01:   75 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   0.2x.
Track 01:   76 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   0.1x.
Track 01:   77 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   0.2x.
Track 01:   78 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   0.1x.
Track 01:   79 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   0.2x.
Track 01:   80 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   0.1x.
Track 01:   81 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   0.2x.
Track 01:   82 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   0.1x.
Track 01:   83 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   0.2x.
Track 01:   84 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   0.1x.
Track 01:   85 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   0.2x.
Track 01:   86 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   0.2x.
Track 01:   87 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   0.2x.
Track 01:   88 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   0.2x.
Track 01:   89 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   0.2x.
Track 01:   90 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   0.2x.
Track 01:   91 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   0.2x.
Track 01:   92 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   0.1x.
Track 01:   93 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   0.2x.
Track 01:   94 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   0.2x.
Track 01:   95 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   0.2x.
Track 01:   96 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   0.2x.
Track 01:   97 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   0.2x.
Track 01:   98 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   0.2x.
Track 01:   99 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   0.2x.
Track 01:  100 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   0.2x.
Track 01:  101 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   0.2x.
Track 01:  102 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   0.2x.
Track 01:  103 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   0.2x.
Track 01:  104 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   0.2x.
Track 01:  105 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   0.2x.
Track 01:  106 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   0.2x.
Track 01:  107 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   0.2x.
Track 01:  108 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   0.2x.
Track 01:  109 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   0.2x.
Track 01:  110 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   0.2x.
Track 01:  111 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   0.2x.
Track 01:  112 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   0.2x.
Track 01:  113 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   0.2x.
Track 01:  114 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   0.2x.
Track 01:  115 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   0.2x.
Track 01:  116 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   0.2x.
Track 01:  117 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   0.2x.
Track 01:  118 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   0.2x.
Track 01:  119 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   0.2x.
Track 01:  120 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   0.2x.
Track 01:  121 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   0.2x.
Track 01:  122 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   0.2x.
Track 01:  123 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   0.2x.
Track 01:  124 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   0.2x.
Track 01:  125 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   0.2x.
Track 01:  126 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   0.2x.
Track 01:  127 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   0.2x.
Track 01:  128 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   0.2x.
Track 01:  129 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   0.2x.
Track 01:  130 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   0.2x.
Track 01:  131 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   0.2x.
Track 01:  132 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   0.2x.
Track 01:  133 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   0.2x.
Track 01:  134 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   0.2x.
Track 01:  135 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   0.2x.
Track 01:  136 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   0.2x.
Track 01:  137 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   0.2x.
Track 01:  138 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   0.2x.
Track 01:  139 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   0.2x.
Track 01:  140 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   0.2x.
Track 01:  141 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   0.2x.
Track 01:  142 of  142 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   0.2x.
Track 01: Total bytes read/written: 148897792/148897792 (72704 sectors).
Writing  time: 3133.095s
Average write speed   0.3x.
Min drive buffer fill was 100%
Fixating...
Fixating time:   17.058s
/opt/schily/bin/cdrecord: fifo had 2346 puts and 2346 gets.
/opt/schily/bin/cdrecord: fifo was 0 times empty and 2267 times full, min fill was 84%.
BURN-Free was never needed.

cdrecord command:
-----------------------
/opt/schily/bin/cdrecord -v gracetime=2 dev=/dev/sr0 speed=24 -sao driveropts=burnfree -data -tsize=72704s -
```

Comment: That's an internal SATA device or external USB? My blind guess would be it's quickly filling approx. 64MB of write cache somewhere and then bottlenecks because the device doesn't like the blank medium. (If you happen to have a different brand of blank around, trying that would be interesting.)

Comment: It is an internal SATA device.